# Convert Dataframe to a list with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, df and df2 as the following image. I would like to convert the df to a list as below. df2 tells which columns to include when the df is converted to a list. How could achieve the goal? Thanks a lot in advanced.

```
desired_output = [{'A': {'value': '10'}, 'B': {'value': '11'}}, {'B': {'value': '14'}, 'C': {'value': '15'}}, {'A': {'value': '16'}, 'B': {'value': '17'}, 'C': {'value': '18'}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds a like it is possibly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want this list for?

Comment: the syntax you posted is is incorrect

Comment: I think the syntax posted is the desired output. I'm confused though why that is the desired output though

Comment: @noah the posted output will return an "Invalid Syntax" error in python.

Comment: I am not disagreeing it is incorrect, I am equally confused why that is the desired output

Comment: @DavidErickson Thanks for pointing that out. It's updated. I'm trying to use it for API request.

Comment: @noah Sorry for any confusion. There were typos. The desired output is updated now! I'm trying to use it for API request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input - Defining datafranes

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,13,16], 'B': [11,14,17], 'C':[12,15,18]} )
df1.index = ['a_0','a_1','a_2']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'start_column': [0,1,0], 'end_column': [1,2,2]} )
df2.index = ['a_0','a_1','a_2']
```

Dataframes input:

```
      A   B   C
a_0  10  11  12
a_1  13  14  15
a_2  16  17  18
     start_column  end_column
a_0             0           1
a_1             1           2
a_2             0           2
```

Solution:

```
def listofdict(j):
    d2 = {}
    x = j['start_column']
    y = j['end_column']+1
    for i in range(x,y):
        d1 = {}
        d1['value'] = str(df1.loc[j.name][i])
        d2[df1.columns[i]] = d1
    l.append(d2)
    return l

l = []
df2.apply(lambda j:listofdict(j), axis=1).all()
print(l)
```

Desired output:

```
[{'A': {'value': '10'}, 'B': {'value': '11'}}, {'B': {'value': '14'}, 'C': {'value': '15'}}, {'A': {'value': '16'}, 'B': {'value': '17'}, 'C': {'value': '18'}}]
```

Comment: does this help @yeonhodev ?